# Grep returns 'grep: node_list.txt: No such file or directory' error

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a script that reads from a file.

```
################################################
#       IP TABLES FOR INSTALL_CONFIG           #
#                                              #
# m = master                                   #
# k = kibana                                   #
# d = data                                     #
# i = ingest                                   #
# c = coordinator                              #
# Format: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx m                    #
################################################
#
10.1.7.93 m
10.1.7.94 k
10.1.7.95 d
```

This is the function that the script uses.

```
function readIpFile () {
    initMasterVar=0

    grep "^[^# ]" node_list.txt | awk '$2 ~ /m/ { print $1 }' > tmp_master_list.txt
    grep "^[^# ]" node_list.txt | awk '$2 ~ /k/ { print $1 }' > tmp_kibana_list.txt
    grep "^[^# ]" node_list.txt | awk '$2 ~ /i/ { print $1 }' > tmp_ingest_list.txt
    grep "^[^# ]" node_list.txt | awk '$2 ~ /d/ { print $1 }' > tmp_data_list.txt
    grep "^[^# ]" node_list.txt | awk '$2 !~ /k/ { print $1 }' > tmp_all_nodes.txt
}
```

The functions purpose is to read from a master node list, it then sorts the list into tmp files according to the role each IP or FQDN is assigned. The grep statement filters all lines that begin with #, and AWK searches the second field for the role, and prints the IP with that role, redirected into a tmp file which is used later in the script.

My problem is that before, this function was working fine. The commands individually work in my terminal and grep is able to locate the file, and filter it accordingly. However when input in this function in this script, it breaks.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. My script when put into shellcheck turns up no errors that would cause this.

Comment: That file doesn't exist in your script's working directory.

Comment: (You can do that all in a single `awk` call, btw. No need for `grep` or multiple runs.)

Comment: The file is uploaded to my test server along with the script. I am able to run the commands from the terminal with no issue.

I am also interested in this single awk call, I read somewhere that it was technically faster to do the filtering with grep, and then pass the output to awk.

Comment: If something is running this script for you, it's entirely possible its working directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: It doesn't matter if node_list.txt exists in the same directory as your script or not, it matters if node_list.txt exists in the same directory as your script is being called from. There are cases where `grep`ing first might make the overall execution a tiny bit faster but there are other cases where it might make it a bit slower so it's not worth worrying about - the difference will be negligible either way, just do it all in awk unless you have a very specific need to do something else.

Comment: Just before your first `grep`, add `pwd`.  You will see in which directory your script actually runs.  Fix as required to be able to read node_list.txt.  Or put the full path to node_list.txt, it will always be ok.

Comment: The absolute path seemed to have done the trick. I had not considered that there would be differences between where the script sits and where it gets called from. Everything is working now!

It is definitely my most ambitious script yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of us mentioned doing all this sorting in a single `awk` script instead of 5 different pipelines as an optimization - that way, the file only has to be read once. One way to do that is using in-`awk` [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection):

```
awk '/^[# ]/   { next } # Skip lines starting with a # or space.
     $2 ~ /m/  { print $1 > "/path/to/tmp_master_list.txt" }
     $2 ~ /k/  { print $1 > "/path/to/tmp_kibana_list.txt" }
     $2 ~ /i/  { print $1 > "/path/to/tmp_ingest_list.txt" }
     $2 ~ /d/  { print $1 > "/path/to/tmp_data_list.txt"   }
     $2 !~ /k/ { print $1 > "/path/to/tmp_all_nodes.txt"   }' /path/to/node_list.txt
```

Comment: I am testing it now, but this is much more compact, I appreciate your suggestion!